# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' , trying to import from a sub package

Tags: python, import, fastapi, subdirectory, supabase

I have this folder structure in my project :

```
easylaw-api/
│
├── src/
│   ├── api/
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models/
│   │   │   ├── codes.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├── routers/
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └── services/
│   │       ├── codes_service.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   │
│   ├── config/
│   │   ├── doNothing.py
│   │   ├── supabase_client.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
```

I have this problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "easylaw-api/src/api/main.py", line 3, in 
from routers import (
File "easylaw-api/src/api/routers/codes.py", line 2, in 
from services import codes_service
File "easylaw-api/src/api/services/codes_service.py", line 7, in 
from src.config.doNothing import doNothing
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

The import statement causing the error is:

`from src.config.doNothing import doNothing`

I understand that this issue might be related to relative imports, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried changing the import to this :
from ..config.doNothing import doNothing
and other variations but nothing worked

Comment: Which file contains the problematic import? And how did you run the project?

Comment: the file code_services.py
from typing import List, Optional
from models.codes import Code

from src.config.doNothing import doNothing


class CodesService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = doNothing()

    async def get_codes(self) -> List[Code]:
        pass


I run the project : (myenv) PS C:\Moncef\Study\PROJET\easylaw-api> python .\src\api\main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run a python file, and the working folder will be the parent folder of this file. So you're running your project with the working folder as ".\src\api" instead of "." which you may want. The module `src` is simply not there, so your program cannot find it, no matter with a direct import or a relative import.

Try moving your main file into the base folder of your project and then switching relative imports accordingly.